# How to group values according to number of occurrence

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable that contain string of numbers which are unique `ids` to some records stored in a database table. The string value could look like this `"3,4,4,6,2,4,7,7,7"` etc.
I use `explode()` function to turn those numbers into an array so that I can use a loop and retrieve the records they identify. I use `array_unique()` to remove reoccurring numbers but I still need a way to know how many times a particular number occurred in the string. Please how could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
array_count_values($array)
```

it give you

```
Array
(
[3] => 1
[4] => 3
[6] => 1
[2] => 1
[7] => 3
)
```